# My Pc not recognize keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I have a "PC" with windows 7 32 bit system. I strated getting keyboard issues. Firsteval only some key was working, but now no key is working. I have verify in Device manager and i figure out that the system not recognizing the keyboard and it showing "driver keyboard pih". how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Is this a laptop? I read "PC" but just has that question in mind. Anyway, did you try another keyboard - just to see if there is a hardware fault with the keyboard?  And also is this a USB keyboard?

Comment: No, it's a PC. I also tried another keyboard but i get the same problem, also i tried the same keyboard in another PC and it works fine. Finally, it's a USB keyboard. I hope this was clear for you.

Comment: Did you try clicking on __Update driver__ from the HID Keyboard properties when you open keyboard properties from Device Manager??

Comment: Yes i plugged the cdrom for drivers, after I click Update driver. but nothing happen

Comment: Please try "Search automatically for updated driver software" option rather than giving the drivers from the CD? Also try an alternate port in the system for the USB keyboard.

Comment: I tried to search automaticaly, but no thing happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by corrupt driver file in the system "Windows 7", i aware that is not the  best answer. But after restoring the system i got my keyboard working just fine. I suggest that the best answer is to fix or change the keyboard driver that exist in windows 7.